# Excel Macro to Bold Based on Column Name and Cell Value

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code, but it looks only in column A. I want the Macro to first find what column is headed, and search by the cell value.

Example. Column name is "Days" (somewhere in the excel sheet) and Cell Value is "Saturday","Sunday". So this way if the Saturday or Sunday is in that row but not that column it wont Bold. Is this possible? Thanks in Advance for any help.

```
Sub Bold_Row_Based_on_Call_Value_and_Column_Name()

Dim cRow As Long
Dim rRow As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
'Gets the last row with data in it
LastRow = [A65000].End(xlUp).Row
'the look to move down the cells
For cRow = 1 To LastRow
'if statment so catch the values that are wanted
If Cells(cRow, 1) = "Saturday" Or Cells(cRow, 1) = "Sunday" Then
'the changes made to the rows
Rows(cRow).Font.Bold = True
End If
Next cRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you add a picture/fragment of your table (one before and another after running the macro)? Your description and example were quite confuse!

Comment: If a cell in column A has "Sunday" or "Saturday", you want the cell in column A bolded?  Isn't that what it does now?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `If` statement to this:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rows(cRow), "Sunday") > 0 Or WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rows(cRow), "Saturday") > 0 Then
        Rows(cRow).Font.Bold = True
End If
```

This will check the row for "Sunday" and "Saturday", and if it's in there, bold the row.

Edit: Per your comment, that "Date" could be in any column, then this should work:

```
Sub Bold_Row_Based_on_Call_Value_and_Column_Name()
Dim cRow As Long, LastRow As Long, daysCol As Long
Dim rRow As Range
'Gets the last row with data in it
LastRow = [A65000].End(xlUp).Row
'the look to move down the cells

daysCol = Rows(1).Find(what:="Days").Column

For cRow = 1 To LastRow
'if statment so catch the values that are wanted
    If Cells(cRow, daysCol) = "Saturday" Or Cells(cRow, dateCol) = "Sunday" Then
        'the changes made to the rows
        Rows(cRow).Font.Bold = True ' This will bold the entire row
        'Cells(cRow, daysCol).Font.Bold = True 'This will bold just the DAY cell
    End If
Next cRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, sorry that is the opposite of what I want, I only want it to bold if the column name "Days" has a "sunday" or "saturday" and ignore those in other columns..

Comment: Where is this column "Days" (column A, B, C...)???

Comment: @DefcaTrick - Do you only want the word "Sunday" and/or "Saturday" to be bold? Then change the `Rows(cRow).Font...` to just `Cells(cRow,1).Font.Bold = True`.  Otherwise, can you please make it more clear what you want bolded? It's a little unclear...

Comment: My apologies for being unclear please use the below as an example: I have 4 columns a Days b Months c Years d Days2. I want to bold the entire line if the word "Sunday" is in a Days. Currently the above code bolds the entire row even if the word "Sunday" is in d Days2. I just want to be specific on the column name and row value to Bold the entire row. I hope that makes sense. ty

Comment: @DefcaTrick - Does the code you put in your original post not do just that???  What does or doesn't the code in your OP do??

Comment: Hello, as I said the code above doesnt look for a column name specifically..so if there is the cell value anywhere it bolds the line..

Comment: @DefcaTrick - It looks *only* in column A.  Are you saying the "Sunday" could be in any other column, and you want the Macro to first find what column is headed "Date", and search that one?

Comment: yes, exactly! sorry i didnt make it clear enough!!

Comment: @DefcaTrick can you edit that note in to your OP and we can see if we can get the question reopened? Thanks!

Comment: done. ty again.

Comment: @DefcaTrick - Thanks. I added some new code, does that do what you're looking for?